# In Rational Gaussian Model, why must $R^2$ be rational?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

I am reading [*Fusion Rules and Modular Transformations in 2D Conformal Field Theory*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(88)90603-7) and Verlinde talks about the *rational gaussian model*.

> The simplest class of RCFT's are the rational gaussian models.  They can be described by a free scalar field $\varphi$ which is compactified on a circle with a rational value of (radius)<sup>2</sup>

What does it mean that the free scalar field is compactified?  And why does it matter that $R^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ ?

---

The action of the Free boson is usually written without every writing a series expansion of the field.

$$ S = \int dz \, d \overline{z} \, \partial X(z,\overline{z}) \partial \overline{X}(z,\overline{z})$$

where I am guessing the domain of integration is all of $\mathbb{C}$.  The variation equation

$$ \partial \overline{\partial} X(z,\overline{z}) = 0 $$

meaning the field breaks into holomorphic and anti-holomorphic parts.  Indeed we can write the field as an infinite series,

$$ \partial X = \sum a_n z^n$$

I don't understand what "compatification" means in this context, or where the rational value of $R^2$ is playing a role.  In this rational theory, how does the formula for $\partial X$ change?

Answer (score 0):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. The *compactified* free scalar field means that the target space is a circle $S^1$ (of radius $R$) rather than the real line $\mathbb{R}$.
2. The condition $R^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ corresponds to a [rational conformal field theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_conformal_field_theory) (RCFT), which means that the CFT only contains a *finite* number of primary fields, and which technically is simpler to treat mathematically.

References:

1. P. Ginsparg, *Applied Conformal Field Theory,*  [arXiv:hep-th/9108028](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028); Chapter 8.